# uninitialized constant NameError when use has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I practice my RoR skills and try develop application to already created DB. It's have 4 tables: *testplans*, *testplan_tcversions*,* test_project* and *nodes*.

I'm code 2 models for this tables:

```
 class TestPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name= 'testplans'

  belongs_to :test_project

  has_many :test_suites, foreign_key: :testplan_id, inverse_of: :test_plan

  has_one :node, foreign_key: :id, inverse_of: :test_plan
end
```

and

```
class TestSuite < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name='testplan_tcversions'
  belongs_to :test_plan

  has_one :node, foreign_key: id, inverse_of: :test_collection
end
```

But I get exception uninitialized constant TestPlan::TestSuite when try: `@suits=TestPlan.find(4906).test_suites`

I found a lot of answers that Models must singular and table must plural, but my Models names are singular, names of tables I point in self.table_name.

What I did wrong?

**UPD**

This my db:schema:dump

```
create_table "testplans", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "testproject_id"
    t.text    "notes"
    t.integer "active"
    t.integer "is_open"
    t.integer "is_public"
    t.text    "api_key"
  end

 create_table "testplan_tcversions", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "testplan_id"
    t.integer  "tcversion_id"
    t.integer  "node_order"
    t.integer  "urgency"
    t.integer  "platform_id"
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.datetime "creation_ts"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

How are your migrations set up?

If they are set up correctly, the relationship between TestSuite and TestPlan should look like this:

```
class TestPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :test_suites
end

class TestSuite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test_plan
end
```

For this to work though, your TestSuite migration needs to have a test_plan_id column. That should look like this.

```
class TestSuite < ActiveRecord::Migration
  belongs_to :test_plan
end
```

If this is set up correctly, you should then be able to call `@suits=TestPlan.find(4906).test_suites`.

Make sure your table names correspond to your model names. If you don't have a table named 'testplan_tcversions', the association isn't going to work.

Comment: I use already created DB and didn't wrote migration, because DB have all tables with fields and data. TestSuite has'n _test_plan_id_ column, but _testplan_id_ and I point it on `foreign_key: :testplan_id`. Table names don't correspond model name, and I use `self.table_name=`